# css framework for draggable page elements and callback for server side position save

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Are there any lightweight frameworks out there for this task. I have a collection of divs, that I want to be able to save positions when dragged/resized/pushed etc.

I was going to build one, to my spec, but if there is a lightweight one out there that might save me a lot of time. I've seen some `jQuery` plugins that push divs around a page fluidly.

I want to be able to save positions, but also snap divs to each other and save all news positions for divs moved or re-sized. I've looked briefly at shindig, but seems a bit heavy... at least I wanted to see if there are any lightweight front end alternatives.

I will be using php for my backend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider midorijs (www.midorijs.com). It is lightweight and contains a simple drag and drop interface complete with a default drop callback function. You can also define your own. You mentioned you wanted a callback for position save, Midori's callback function does pass the x,y coordinates of the object.

Chceck out more drag and drop callback details at the bottom of this page: http://www.midorijs.com/midoriDragDrop.html

Another benefit since you mentioned you are using php is Midori's convertToFields function which converts javascript object to php.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Why not using jQuery ui? You can customize a bundle to fit your needs + when delivering from googlecode you can get sure that a huge amount of users already have that in their cache. And you can easily get the positionings and push them to your server.

http://jqueryui.com/download

Comment: im using that, and I can capture the positions. But im looking for a framework that can handle multiple elements and their positions. I want to know if there is a solution out there already. I could write my own like you suggest, but im lazy and i dont want to. ;-)

Comment: I see, you rather spend your time procrastinating with asking questions on how to do something, while you could already have done it :p Couldnt you easily extend jquery ui to fit your requirements? Seems like a quick hacky session :)

Comment: ok, im not even sure if jquery ui handles fluid divs for example. If i resize one div and it repositions/resizes its siblings, and secondly each new position and resize value needs saved for each one. Im not procrastinating, i'm asking if there is something out there already that handles this. If not, then i will get hacking.

Comment: @Christoph: jquery-ui is lightweight depending on what widged you use!

Comment: why is the answer to every javascript questions -- use jquery

Comment: I have managed to implement a drag-and-drop-interface with jQ-UI very easy, features are: Multiple (variable) elements and their position have been used.

Every time a element is positioned, a short Ajax-Call notified the server. No big deal. Just be sure to use ids or id-like-desctiptions for the elements.